# Does 'ssh <remote> -t <command>' has a timeout? killed by Signal 15

Tags: linux, centos, ssh

I want to run a job on remote server with no login. I found that I can run my job using ssh as:

```
ssh remotenode -t /path/to/myjob &> /path/to/log
```

However, the job would be killed by Signal 15 after a while. Does SSH force some timeout?

NOTE: My jobs takes a few hours to be completed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I may suggest using screen

```
ssh remotenode -t "screen -S ServerFault top"
```

This will start screened *top* process with session name 'ServerFault' . Later on you can simply re-attach this on remotenode using

`screen -r ServerFault`

Comment: Thanks. Then should I run the job as `ssh remotenode -t "screen -S ServerFault /path/to/myjob &> /path/to/log "` ?

Comment: no need for &; just ctrl+a+d to detach screen and process will be left running on remotenode until you ssh to remotenode and run 'screen -r ServerFault' to check what is happening with your process